# django subclass not calling superclass (derived from modelform) clean method

Tags: python, django, oop, inheritance, django-forms

I have a django form (formA) that inherits from modelform.

In another app, I have a form that derives from that form (formB).

This all works ok, including obtaining fields from the base class formA, but when the clean method is called, it doesn't call the formA clean method.  Instead it skips formA, and calls django's modelform.clean.

I can create a clean method in formB and this is called, but calling the super().clean() method also steps immediately into django's modelform.clean.

Why might this be happening and what do I have to do to get the correct inheritance chain for the clean method?

MTIA

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the different apps were in different venv prefixes, and this was why the inheritance wasn't working.
So, all fixed now.